# .htaccess rewritebase + index file url not ofsetting (PHP / Apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

ok,

So here is my .htaccess with the RewriteBase set to `/abc/public/`. The index.php file is located in the `/public/` folder which is a subfolder of `/abc/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /abc/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I retrieve the `$_GET['url']` value from within my script, there is always the value `public` at the `$url[0]` index. Now, why is the `public` being passed to the index.php if the rewrite base is set to `/abc/public/` ?

Shouldn't it just start to pass values after `/public/` ? So say i have `/abc/public/method/params/`, if I output `print_r($url)`, should I not get `$url[0] = 'method', $url[1] = 'params'` ??

Can't seem to figure this one out.

EDIT:

Mods, please disregard last flag. Turns out this question is after all relevant.

Comment: How do you turn `$_GET['url']` into `$url`? `split()`? `"public"` should not be in `$_GET['url']`.

Comment: sorry, I just parse it in a function as such: `return (isset($_GET['url'])) ? str_ireplace('-', '', explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/')), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)) : null;`

Comment: Ok, so what is the value of `$_GET['url']` going into this?

Comment: for example, if I access '/public/abc/', then the value that goes into my parse function is 'public/abc'. If I have just '/public/', then the parse function returns null as it sees $_GET['url'] as empty.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: it is located in one level up on public. for example, if /abc/public/, the .htaccess is in /abc/

Comment: ok, so I placed the .htaccess in the /public/ folder and it's fine now. @anubhava if you want to make an answer based on your question, I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe .htaccess is not placed in correct directory based on your `RewriteBase` value. For example if you're using:

```
RewriteBase /abc/public/
```

Then correct location of .htaccess should be:

```
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/abc/public/
```